# Liquid benzene magnetic susceptibility

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, magnetic-fields

In a solid state physics problem, I'm asked to make a rough estimate of the contribution to the diamagnetic susceptibility of the outer electron of each carbon atom. The wavefunction of these electrons extend round the whole ring of atoms. The only data I'm given is the benzene hexagon side length, 1 A; the benzene density, and the molecular weight.

Attempt of a solution: I think that I have to consider the effect of an applied magnetic field B perpendicular to the plane of the hexagonal molecule. That will make the outer electrons move along the ring, generating a current that generates a magnetic field opposing B. Am I right? If yes, how to derive the magnetic susceptibility following this line of reasoning?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Just some pointers to get you started: The side length allows you to calculate the flux through a benzene ring given a magnetic field, which should then give you the induced current, if you claim that the electrons in the benzene ring are metallic (not a bad approximation due to their delocalized nature)

Comment: You might also want to look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aromatic_ring_current

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just some pointers to get you started: The side length allows you to calculate the flux through a benzene ring given a magnetic field, which should then give you the induced current, if you claim that the electrons in the benzene ring are metallic (not a bad approximation due to their delocalized nature).

Another thing you can look at is this article on aromatic ring currents,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aromatic_ring_current